# Application with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

Recently, I started using a Java application a former colleague of mine designed. After performing certain actions, the application freezes and the error.log file shows the following:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BATBlock.<init>(BATBlock.java:57)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BATBlock.<init>(BATBlock.java:210)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BATBlock.createBATBlocks(BATBlock.java:87)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockAllocationTableWriter.simpleCreateBlocks(BlockAllocationTableWriter.java:150)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.BlockAllocationTableWriter.createBlocks(BlockAllocationTableWriter.java:103)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.writeFilesystem(POIFSFileSystem.java:221)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:744)
    at net.ndmystko.qa.QAJobReporter.writeWorkbook(QAJobReporter.java:478)
    at net.ndmystko.qa.QAJobReporter.writeResults(QAJobReporter.java:458)
    at net.ndmystko.qa.QAJobReporter.writeResults(QAJobReporter.java:402)
    at net.ndmystko.qa.QA.displayEvolutionProgress(QA.java:1257)
    at net.ndmystko.qa.QA.access$9(QA.java:1186)
    at net.ndmystko.qa.QA$4.actionPerformed(QA.java:1176)
    at net.ndmystko.analysis.evolution.Evolution.run(Evolution.java:191)
```

I have read that I would need to increase the heap size allotted to the application. However, I do not know how to achieve this, or where I could enter the code needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am not experienced in programming. I run the program from a .bat file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase heap size in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following Java commandline parameters

```
-Xms: initial heap size
-Xmx: Maximum heap size
```

Set it when you run your application, e.g.

```
java -Xmx1024m YourClass
```

for allocating 1024 MB

```
java -Xmx2g YourClass
```

for allocating 2 GB

Edit: In regard to your note the java command is probably inside the .bat file. So you should open it up, find the java command and add the commandline arguments there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I opened up command prompt and typed the code you suggested: java -Xmx2g MyApplication.bat. It did not seem to work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since it is a .bat file the java command is probably inside the .bat file. Have a look in the file and there should be a command starting with java. There you can add the parameter.

Comment: I opened up the .bat file and entered following code:

Comment: (java -cp quanta.jar;evol_engine.jar;jdom.jar;jakarta-poi.jar net.ndmystko.qa.QA SCK 2> error.log
java -Xmx2g) It still does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just put the -Xmx2g after the initial `java` at the beginning of the line, e.g.  `java -Xmx2g -cp ...`

Comment: Now the application does not run anymore. Do I need to add anything after the -Xmx2g?

Comment: If you just take the original command and add -Xmx2g after the initial java command it should look like the following: `java -Xmx2g -cp quanta.jar;evol_engine.jar;jdom.jar;jakarta-poi.jar net.ndmystko.qa.QA SCK 2> error.log`. If it does not start there should be an error message. Have a look in the error log. Alternatively you can also remove `2> error.log` and add a pause command below the java command and execute the .bat. This will leave the commandline window open after the program terminates.

Comment: The bat file looks like the following: java -Xmx2g -cp quanta.jar;evol_engine.jar;jdom.jar;jakarta-poi.jar net.ndmystko.qa.QA SCK 2> error.log. When I run it, a prompt flashes quickly and nothing happens after. The error.log file remains empty.

Comment: If you put `pause` below the java command the prompt should stay open and there should be some kind of message.

Comment: The prompt reads: Error occurred during initialization of VM. Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Comment: Then it seems that you have not enough memory =). Try with e.g. 1024m.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Strange, considering I have 8g of RAM. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No problem. I guess you are using a 32-bit JRE and with that you cannot allocate more than about 1.5GB. So if you want to allocate more memory you have to install a 64-bit JRE.